# groff putting single word on line after trap

Tags: groff, troff

I have a groff document, however, when I set the trap to create a footer, groff puts one word after the specified height, then executes the macro for the trap. I am compilinig the document with `groff -Tpdf -P-pletter ex.groff > ex.pdf`.

ex.groff:

```
.de foot
.  bp
..
.wh -1i foot
.ls 2
.nh
.ad l
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
In pulvinar, ex id ultricies tincidunt, ligula neque hendrerit velit, id feugiat enim nisl eu justo.
In bibendum elementum auctor.
Fusce dapibus sed nulla in malesuada.
Ut vehicula ultrices nibh, at iaculis est consectetur vitae.
Phasellus condimentum est in elit ultrices mattis.
Mauris orci sem, dictum eleifend augue vitae, fermentum convallis nunc.
In semper vitae nunc a congue.
Pellentesque pretium risus vitae turpis mollis, a blandit lacus vestibulum.
Vivamus congue urna mauris, ac viverra ipsum tristique id.
Maecenas mauris massa, ullamcorper eu fringilla consequat, molestie ac nunc.
Etiam luctus tortor id odio fringilla, eu eleifend leo imperdiet.
.br
Integer venenatis et mi dignissim dictum.
Duis rutrum tortor lectus, eget pulvinar risus viverra id.
Vivamus vel vestibulum neque, in posuere libero.
Praesent eu erat ut ligula consequat consectetur sed nec magna.
Pellentesque vitae rhoncus felis.
Suspendisse potenti.
Nullam in sodales nisi.
Nulla vitae tempus sem, non laoreet felis.
.br
Fusce velit metus, condimentum non ultricies facilisis, dignissim eu diam.
Donec lorem ante, pulvinar et congue non, iaculis ac leo.
Nam sit amet risus dui.
Mauris lorem nunc, facilisis non odio dapibus, gravida posuere leo.
Quisque pellentesque tincidunt dolor sed eleifend.
Nam eget augue feugiat, tincidunt orci et, tempor quam.
Suspendisse purus mi, mollis quis porta quis, tincidunt vel odio.
Pellentesque nisl sapien, posuere sed accumsan eget, elementum vel est.
Maecenas cursus neque quis arcu varius, at efficitur dui dictum.
.br
Etiam semper ultrices ipsum, eget gravida risus condimentum vel.
Suspendisse sed tincidunt lectus.
Suspendisse faucibus gravida lorem, vel volutpat eros hendrerit nec.
Vestibulum ac leo eget metus sollicitudin rhoncus.
Fusce venenatis ligula a sodales varius.
Etiam mauris nisi, ultricies eu ex quis, vehicula facilisis nulla.
Pellentesque eu arcu nec urna tempor fringilla.
Sed consectetur, leo at convallis finibus, nunc mi feugiat dolor, a tincidunt tortor ipsum vitae sem.
Vestibulum tincidunt, nisl vel hendrerit consequat, leo felis rutrum tellus, quis tempor odio leo in lectus.
Donec placerat tempor turpis nec efficitur.
Donec quis erat a augue tempor lacinia sit amet ac felis.
Donec a dui ut diam tempus cursus.
Sed auctor, lorem sed interdum blandit, erat dui tristique dolor, vitae condimentum lorem dui ac augue.
.br
Phasellus et dignissim lacus.
Vestibulum a dolor sodales est bibendum sodales.
Nulla gravida erat lacus, in placerat sapien consequat id.
Donec vitae pulvinar neque.
Etiam a semper augue.
Phasellus sed justo id velit imperdiet finibus.
Nam eget vulputate orci, ac congue nunc.
Pellentesque sollicitudin, nulla quis luctus pulvinar, velit ex feugiat leo, sed euismod ante odio at est.
Duis velit sapien, ornare vel vulputate in, consectetur non neque.
Curabitur non libero at magna venenatis cursus et vel urna.
.br
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
In pulvinar, ex id ultricies tincidunt, ligula neque hendrerit velit, id feugiat enim nisl eu justo.
In bibendum elementum auctor.
Fusce dapibus sed nulla in malesuada.
Ut vehicula ultrices nibh, at iaculis est consectetur vitae.
Phasellus condimentum est in elit ultrices mattis.
Mauris orci sem, dictum eleifend augue vitae, fermentum convallis nunc.
In semper vitae nunc a congue.
Pellentesque pretium risus vitae turpis mollis, a blandit lacus vestibulum.
Vivamus congue urna mauris, ac viverra ipsum tristique id.
Maecenas mauris massa, ullamcorper eu fringilla consequat, molestie ac nunc.
Etiam luctus tortor id odio fringilla, eu eleifend leo imperdiet.
```

which produces the undesired word right after the trap height (the word on the final line should be on the next page)
[image: undesired word after trap instead of on next page]
How can I make it so this word appears on the next page, instead of right where the trap should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have the reference to hand, but from my notes, in the table listing the basic troff commands we have

```
.bp +-N     N=1     Bbv    new page. number of next page
```

where `Bbv` are a set of flags including this: *b will cause line break unless use `'` instead of `.`*  so the answer is to define your macro to call `'bp` instead of `.bp`.

```
.de foot
'  bp
..
```

---

The online groff doc briefly says about [requests](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Requests.html):

> A request line begins with a control character, which is either a
>         single quote (`'`, the no-break control character) or a period (`.`,      the normal control character).

and for [bp](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Page-Control.html) has an example using `'bp`.